# Components of weight while banking

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

If I have a plane thats  banking, am I right in saying that the centripetal force pulls it towards a centre. What happens to weight?

[image]

I understand that it breaks into parallel and perpendicular components along the wing. I don't understand how forces having $x$- and $y$-components relate to other forces that have component parallel and perpendicular to something. In other words, how do I resolve these forces?

Answer (score 0):

The force missing from your diagram is lift, which acts at right angles to the line of the plane's wings. There is no separate centripetal force acting on the plane (where would it come from ?)- the centripetal force is simply the horizontal component of lift. The vertical component of lift counteracts the weight of the plane. If the plane is in level flight then the vertical component of lift must be equal and opposite to the plane's weight.